# AsserrtTemplateUsed fails despite template being used...?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a view:

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard/dashboard.html"
```

Which I am testing using `TestCase`:

```
class TestAuthorisedViews(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.url = reverse('dashboard')
        cls.client = Client()
        cls.response = cls.client.get(cls.url)

    def test_view_uses_correct_template(self):
        print('template', self.response.__dict__)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, 'dashboard/dashboard.html')
```

This test fails with `AssertionError: No templates used to render the response`.

However, the `print()` debug I included in the test reveals the response **does** use a template:

```
template {'template_name': ['dashboard/dashboard.html'], 'context_data': {
     'view': <dashboard.views.DashboardView object at 0x0000019E9CF33040> }, // etc >}
```

Am I using this test correctly? When looking at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5d4b9c1cab03f0d057f0c7751862df0302c65cf9/django/test/testcases.py#L620), it seems the error fails because `response.templates = []` rather than `response.templates = None`.

Comment: what is returned when you print the `template_name`?

Comment: `print(self.response.template_name)` results in `['dashboard/dashboard.html']`

Comment: hmh damn, that actually looks good to me... somehow it doesn't recognize the template_name as template_name since it raises the error because of `if not template_names`

Comment: did you try `self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, self.template_name='dashboard/dashboard.html')`

Comment: Yes (I assume you mean `template_name='dashboard/dashboard.html'`), it results in the same error